# Join two tables through a pivot table and retrieve specific results in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have an issue with my logic, because i'm not an expert on DB. I have three tables, a users table that looks like this:

```
id|name |type_id|
 1|user1|   1   |
 2|user2|   2   |
 3|user3|   2   |
 4|user4|   2   |
```

where the user type id '2' means manager. A companies table:

```
id | name |
 1 | shoes|
 2 | pants|
 3 | tv   |
 4 | light|
```

And a pivot table (companies_manager) which assigns one or more managers to a one or more companies:

```
id|manager_id |company_id|
 1|     2     |     1    |
 2|     3     |     2    |
 3|     4     |     3    |
 4|     3     |     3    |
```

As you look, a single company can have one or more managers and vice versa. The problem appears when I want to retrieve the managers (in other words, users with user type id '2') that do not belong to a certain company (the company 1 for example, retrieve the users 3 and 4) but I don't really know how to make the query, because althought they do not belong to the company 1, they belong to another company. Thanks for advance!

Comment: Still struggling? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
SELECT user.*, compnies.*, compnies_manager.* FROM user LEFT JOIN compnies_manager ON user.type_id=compnies_manager.manager_id LEFT JOIN compnies ON compnies_manager.compny_id=compnies.id WHERE user.type_id=2
```